# Copying my iphone stuff to android?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, android

I've got a ton of purchased and non-purchased music on my iphone. Same with movies. I've also got a pretty big collection of audio books. I'd like to dump a copy onto my android tablet. Is there any way to pull all the media off my iphone and strip freeplay so i can copy it into my android?

Bonus points if I can also transfer text history, apps, etc. Ideally I'd like to just run 'something' that will make my android have everything my iphone has.

Comment: Interesting. There are several great apps to go from Android to iOS. The [Relo app by JAMF Software](https://appsto.re/us/gNBz5.i) is the one I rely on. Hopefully someone has made the reverse....

Comment: I've used Relo before, and I was positive I'd find something for ios -> android, but sadly, no such luck so far. Perhaps my google-fu is just weak.

Comment: This is kind of off-topic, but you'd be better off with just buying a used iPad off of eBay, if you want a tablet that plays nice with your iPhone. A used one can be relatively cheap, too, as you should be able to find a 1st-gen for less than $100, maybe a bit more for an iPad 2 or 3 or another newer model.

Comment: I have an ipad, it works great.. I just want my android one to work too..

Answer (score 1):

You will have far better luck syncing the iPhone to a computer or otherwise getting the media from a computer to Andriod.

The economics of the flow is such that people seem motivated to make quality tools for Andriod to iOS but not the other way.

On Mac, your first step at liberating data might be a tool like Phoneview. It hits your music sync, text history sync and can generate a list of apps I believe.

Comment: I'm perfectly fine doing that.. I just cant find anything that will suck down all my movies/music/etc. and strip FreePlay.. I'll take a look at Phoneview -- thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @XeroxDucati FreePlay is iTunes DRM (Digital Rights Management, or copy projection), right? Because as far that goes, unfortunately, any application that removes the DRM from your iTunes content will likely be illegal. I absolutely hate DRM, but AFAIK there's there's no safe and legal way to remove it from your content.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 We shy away from legal here since it's so hyper-local and also depends on things that really aren't relevant. If someone asks how to remove drm - it's nice to point out clear legal issues, but we also serve adult and researchers where people have legitimate reasons for breaking a license or even a law. It would probably be better to worry about DRM as a separate thread, so that's why I ignored it entirely in my answer.